# How to get index of neighboring repeating elements within a Python list?

Tags: python, list, indexing, repeat

What is a fast way to get index of only neighboring repeating elements within a Python list?

```
# Have 
list1 = [2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6]
#        0  1  2        5  6  7

# Want
index = [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: is your list guaranteed to be sorted in ascending order?

Comment: not specifically sorted, but arranged in such a way repeating elements are next to each other

Answer (score 4):

A set will be very handy to avoid having duplicates, and once you have the indices you can covert it back to a list and sort it, so try the following:

```py
# Have 
list1 = [2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6]
#        0  1  2        5  6  7

result = set()
for i in range(1, len(list1)):
    if list1[i - 1] == list1[i]:
        result.add(i - 1)
        result.add(i)
index = sorted(list(result))
```

Comment: How is the second more efficient? The `not in` operation and `in` take `O(n)` to compute each! Just look at the last element of `result` to see if it already exists

Comment: @MZ, the problem is that in the first approach I am using `sorted` which will take in the base case `O(n log(n))`.

Comment: `O(n^2)` is worse. Just look at the last element in `result` and you'll see if you need to add an index or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to handle the grouping of neighbouring repeated elements:

```
from itertools import groupby

list1 = [2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6]

index, i = [], 0
for k, g in groupby(list1):
    grp = len(list(g))
    if grp > 1:
        index.extend(range(i, i+grp))
        i += grp
    else:
        i += 1
    
print(index)
# [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Note: you can simply do `index.extend(range(i, i+grp))`

Answer (score 1):

easy in pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
ids = df.index[(df[0].diff() == 0) | (df[0].diff(-1) == 0)].values
```

output:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7])
```

Comment: you are suggesting to install a library just to solve this problem...

Comment: i dunno i figure posting a solution using one of the most popular pkgs in the world might me useful to some who use it

Answer (score 1):

Here's an `O(n)` solution. Based upon @lmiguelvargasf 's answer.

```py
list1 = [2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6]
#        0  1  2        5  6  7

index = []

last = False
for i in range(1, len(list1)):
    if list1[i - 1] != list1[i]:
        last = False
    elif last:
        index.append(i)
        last = True
    else:
        index.append(i - 1)
        index.append(i)
        
        last = True
```

Your result will be sorted. Pretty sure this is as quick as it gets :D.
Not as short and clean but definitely fast.

Answer (score 0):

After figuring out for a while, I came out with a fast way using numpy without using slower nested for loops:

*(Improving solution thanks to answer below from* @lmiguelvargasf)

```
dup_ix = [(i, i-1) for i in range(1, len(list1)) if list1[i] == list1[i-1]]
    
dup_ix = np.array(dup_ix).flatten() 
dup_ix = list(set(dup_ix))
    
print(dup_ix)
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Hey, if you're curious I've posted a faster solution (`O(n)`), but glad to see you found a solution that works for you!

Comment: Hey @M Z, thanks for commenting. Think the ```last = False``` might not be needed as the ```i``` range already takes care of that?

Comment: Pretty sure you need it, or something similar to it, in order to manage some edge cases.